# How to connect divs with a line

Tags: html, css

I've got something like this:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPSoJ.png):

[image]

I have created some div elements, and styled them as I wanted. How to connect these div elements with lines, as I've drawn in the picture above?

Here is my current code:

```css
.plan-tor {
  height: 0px;
  width: 97%;
  background-color: black;
  border: 20px solid white;
  padding: 4px 4px;
}

.plan-peron {
  border: 3px double black;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: auto;
}

.noline-bottom {
  border-bottom-style: none;
}

.noline-top {
  border-top-style: none;
}

#parent2 {
  display: flex;
}

#P51 {
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 25%;
}

#P52 {
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 25%;
  flex: 1;
}

#P61 {
  width: 20%;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

#P62 {
  width: 20%;
  margin-top: 14px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

#T51 {
  width: 67%;
}

#T52 {
  width: 47%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  flex: 1;
}

#T61 {
  width: 25%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="plan-tor" id="T62"></div>
<div class="parent2">
  <div class="plan-peron noline-bottom" id="P62">Peron 6-2</div>
  <div class="plan-tor" id="T52"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent2">
  <div class="plan-peron noline-top" id="P61">Peron 6-1</div>
  <div style="color: white;"> ' </div>
  <div class="plan-tor" id="T61"></div>
  <div class="plan-peron noline-bottom" id="P52">Peron 5-2</div>
</div>
<div class="plan-peron noline-top" id="P51">Peron 5-1</div>
<div class="plan-tor" id="T51"></div>
<div class="plan-tor" id="T42"></div>
<div class="plan-peron noline-bottom" id="P42">Peron 4-2</div>
<div class="plan-peron noline-top" id="P41">Peron 4-1</div>
<div class="plan-tor" id="T41"></div>
```

Comment: Can it be a fixed width and height or do you want it to be responsive?

Comment: I feel that a good answer to this question depends quite a lot on the information you're trying to convey; what is this chart *for*? What information is displaying? Why do some lines connect to others? What are the groups of "perons" about (did you mean "person"?)

Answer (score 0):

So I guess the problem is the red diagonal lines. If you're using a fixed width it's just some fiddling with the rotate settings. If you want it to be responsive you should probably have it calculated with JS.

Here is an example with a fixed width:
I've used `position: absolute;` on all elements to give them the appropriate positions and sizes.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  width: 95%; /*so if you want it to be responsive this one*/
  width: 750px; /*used a fixed size to have the red lines always at the same degrees */
  margin: 1em auto;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0.5em;
  background-color: black;
}

.one {
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.two {
  width: 33.3%;
  top: 3.5em;
  left: 33.3%;
}

.three {
  width: 25%;
  top: 6.5em;
  left: 75%;
}

.four {
  width: 66.6%;
  top: 9.5em;
  left: 0;
}

.five {
  width: 100%;
  top: 13em;
  left: 0;
}

.six {
  width: 100%;
  top: 18.5em;
  left: 0;
}


.red-line{
  position: absolute;
  height: 0.3em;
  background-color: red;
}

.red-one {
  transform: rotate(39deg);
  width: 10.8%;
  top: 5.1em;
  left: 65.5%;
}

.red-two {
  transform: rotate(-39deg);
  width: 10.8%;
  top: 8.1em;
  left: 65.5%;
}

.red-three {
  transform: rotate(-39deg);
  width: 20%;
  top: 6.5em;
  left: 15.8%;
}

.perron {
  position: absolute;
  height: 2em;
  border: 5px double grey;
  text-align: center;
}

.perron-six {
  width: 15%;
  top: 2.5em;
  left: 80%;
}

.perron-five {
  width: 20%;
  top: 5.5em;
  left: 40%; 
}


.perron-four {
  width: 40%;
  top: 15em;
  left: 40%; 
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="line one"></span>
  <span class="line two"></span>
  <span class="line three"></span>
  <span class="line four"></span>
  <span class="line five"></span>
  <span class="line six"></span>
  
  <span class="red-line red-one"></span>
  <span class="red-line red-two"></span>
  <span class="red-line red-three"></span>
  
  <span class="perron perron-six"></span>
  <span class="perron perron-five"></span>
  <span class="perron perron-four"></span>
</div>
```